# Boot Camp error "Windows cannot locate the disk and partition"

Tags: macos, windows, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition

[image]I have a 2019 MacBook Pro 16 inch running on macOS Big Sur 11.1.
I am trying to install windows using Bootcamp. I get the following error:

**Windows cannot locate the disk and partition specified in the unattended answer file's  setting. Make sure the setting references a valid partition and restart the installation.**

Can someone help me how to solve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: …not without knowing what your unattend.xml says

Comment: Where can i find or generate the unattended.xml file

Comment: Hmmm… it seems BC changed how it's written. Have a look at this (which is a bit beyond me, I think;) https://twocanoes.com/boot-camp-changes-on-t2-macs/ I don't have a T2 mac to compare to.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But how do I add this to the iso file?

Comment: If you're not starting from a Win iso but entirely via BC then I'm not sure. I was imagining an earlier process, before the T2 Macs. idk the new structure at all, sorry.

Comment: Are you trying to install Windows someplace other than the internal drive? Is Big Sur installed on the internal drive?

Comment: I am trying it on the internal drive with 100gb for windows and 400gb for macOS. Big Sur is installed on the internal drive

Comment: Can you add the output from `diskutil list` to your question?

Comment: i had deleted the bootcamp and osxreserved partition immediately... since idk if it is gonna affect

Comment: Post the output from `diskutil list`. I just want to know how the disk is currently partitioned. The command does not change anything.

Comment: added the image... please refer to it

Answer (score 1):

You do not have an EFI partition. You output from `diskutil list` should look something like below. Here `disk0s1` is the EFI partition. This is missing in your output.

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *273.7 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk1⁩         273.4 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +273.4 GB   disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume ⁨MyBigSur - Data⁩         8.4 GB     disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume ⁨Preboot⁩                 292.2 MB   disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume ⁨Recovery⁩                613.6 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume ⁨VM⁩                      1.1 MB     disk1s4
   5:                APFS Volume ⁨MyBigSur⁩                15.0 GB    disk1s5
   6:              APFS Snapshot ⁨com.apple.os.update-...⁩ 15.0 GB    disk1s5s1
```

There is a good chance the EFI partition was deleted and can be recreated. You would first need to post the output from the following command.

```
diskutil info disk0s1 | grep -e Offset -e Size
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... I downgraded my mac to Catalina and it worked perfectly. the BCA is not a stable one in Big Sur

Comment: You probably are wrong about the BCA in Big Sur being the problem. Another [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/412146/bootcamp-tested-disks) was posted after your question describing the same problem. Here, instead of no EFI partition, there were two EFI partitions. I assume your downgrade created the missing EFI partition, thus allowing the installation of Windows via the BCA. I suppose now that Windows is installed, you could upgrade back to Big Sur, if you wanted to.

Comment: ok... I will maybe work with Catalina and if required upgrade to big sur... just finished setting up and copying my backups