# Boot Camp error "Windows cannot locate the disk and partition specified in the unattended answer's file"

Tags: macos, windows, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition

[image]I have a 2019 MacBook Pro 16 inch running on macOS Big Sur 11.1.
I am trying to install windows using Bootcamp. I get the following error:

**Windows cannot locate the disk and partition specified in the unattended answer file's < ImageInstall > setting. Make sure the setting references a valid partition and restart the installation.**

Attached the image of my disk utility without Bootcamp partition and the Image of the error.

Can someone help me how to solve this?

Thanks in advance
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot... Hw\ow can I do that?

Comment: I started to post instructions, then realized you are missing the EFI partition. See my answer posted in the [other question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/411881/boot-camp-error-windows-cannot-locate-the-disk-and-partition).