# Bootcamp & Tested Disks

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, disk-utility

My bootcamp doesn't work, at the windows set up page I get "windows cannot locate the disk and partition specified in the unattended answer..." which I think is due to the weird nested disks I have
[image]

How can I clean up the way that the disk is formatted? I don't want this pointless nested disks

*MacBook Pro 2016 Big Sur

Comment: what macOS version are you on? This actually looks normal if you are on a newer macOS like BigSur or Catalina.

Comment: That disk layout looks correct for a pre-boot camp Mac. If you delete them, you’re deleting the system and data volumes inside the APFS container. Do you have a backup or can start everything over?

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the model/year of your Mac? You are the second user in a week to post this type of [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/411881/boot-camp-error-windows-cannot-locate-the-disk-and-partition). Also, did you have any external drives attached when you tried to install Windows?

Comment: @DavidAnderson I dont have any externals attached

Comment: You could add the output from the commands `diskutil list` and `sw_vers`. These commands will not change your Mac. At this point, you might be better off trying to install without the use of the unattended answer file.

Comment: The other user who has this same problem was missing the hidden EFI partition. Would be interested in knowing if you are missing this same partition.

Comment: @DavidAnderson no I wasn't missing an EFI partition

Answer (score -1):

1. as many people have said, a lot of people were missing their EFI partition so if you do diskutil list in your terminal and you don't have an EFI partition then that's where you went wrong
2. what was wrong with mine was that I had TWO EFI partitions, so I had to get rid of the extra pointless one and it worked